# windows C program perform action on shutdown

Tags: c, windows

I am making a program that sends "heartbeats" for a server to keep track of nodes. They are packets with the following payloads:

- 'start' when it starts up
- 'running' every 5 seconds
- 'stopping' at shutdown

The first two are easy. The thread/loop can set the message on first and subsequent runs. How do I make the loop "catch" a shutdown so that it can send a last packet?

I use the minGW compiler for C in WinXP platform.

Edit: I added the relevant details I missed (thanks walkingTarget and Ferruccio)

- It is an in-progress app that contains messy stuff in implementation :-)
- It uses libCURL, the HTTP client library to send the packets
- It is a console app, which I (much later) intend as a service
- It needs to save a file and send a packet at shutdown
- It needs to capture a system shutdown

Comment: Are you using Sockets or another networking library?

Comment: I am using libCURL, which I configured for POST

Comment: Is your program a service, a console mode app or a GUI app? Are you trying to capture a system shutdown, a user logging off or the app terminating?

Comment: Its a console app and its trying to capture system shutdowns.

Answer (score 1):

In your WindowProc() you can check for the message WM_QueryEndSession, which Windows sends to all open processes before shutting down. For more info on that message see the following link, but i understand that it is as trivial as checking for a WM_SIZE:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376890%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: If you are using a Console application then install an `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` this way you get a notification when the console window is about to close and therefore your application about to exit.